# Core bluetooth framework not scanning all BLE device and apple BLE devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am using Core bluetooth framework and scanning few devices such as micromax A250,micromax A116 , samsung grand neo, HTC 610 and ipod 5s then i am not able to scan samsung, HTC and ipod what could be the reason? Please help me to resolve thankyou in advance.

**code**

```
// object creation



@IBAction func btnScanClicked(sender:UIButton)
    {

        var centralManager:CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        self.centralManager = centralManager
    }

 //   method called whenever the device state changes.

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {

        if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff
        {
            println("bluetooth is off")
        }
        else if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn
        {
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil) // scanning devices
            println("bluetooth is on")

        }
        else if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unknown
        {
            println("bluetooth is unknown")
        }
        else if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported
        {
            println("bluetooth is unsupported")
        }
    }

// method to discover peripherals:- 

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!)

    {
        if peripheral != nil{
                println("discovered \(peripheral.name)")
        }
        else
        {
            println("No device found")
        }
        self.peripheral = peripheral
        peripheral.delegate = self
        central!.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
    }

// method to connect:-

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!)

    {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        if ((peripheral) != nil)
        {
            var state = peripheral.state == CBPeripheralState.Connected ? "yes" : "no"
            connected = "Connected \(state)"
            println("connected \(connected)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know that those devices are advertising BLE services?  Have you tried the LightBlue app from the app store?

Comment: These all devices are bluetooth version 4.0 so it must be BLE device and i have not tried LightBlue app what it is i dont know about that thing.

Comment: Just because those devices are BT 4.0 doesn't mean that they are actively advertising services. At face value your code looks OK and it is finding some devices, so that is why it is good to check with another app.  The LightBlue app is free and will display advertising BLE devices - https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/lightblue-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110?mt=8

Comment: That isn't a solution, just a suggested troubleshooting tool. You need to confirm that these devices are indeed advertising a BLE service. A known working app is a good way of doing that

Comment: To rephrase @Paulw11: A BLE device needs to be advertising to be "discoverable". In other words, a BLE device will say "Hey, I'm here", and the BLE device scanning will be able to find it. But it the first one does not say "Hey, I'm here", the second won't be able to find it. LightBlue, which scan "correctly", may also advertise. In that way, you can check with it if your issue is because of your scan (there are options to it), or it is because the other ones aren't advertising.

Comment: @Larme then if you are saying it is issue regarding advertising how some device advertise and some don't how should i make all them to advertise?

Comment: You have to code that part, or use an app that advertise (there should be some equivalent to LightBlue in Android).

Comment: @Larme So far I searched code of core bluetooth framework in apple's site no where I found such thing that we have to make device to advertise as it can be done by itself then what could be reason that some device get scanned and some don't.

Comment: I have tested in LightBlue app it is also showing same problem not able to detect please help me out in some way.

Comment: That's the iOS Sample code : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: It is not working I have tried this code also and some device are not getting scanned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android OS does not support using the phone as a peripheral, only as a master.

The iPhone will not behave as a peripheral unless it is running software to do so. You can find example code for an iOS device advertising as a peripheral in Apple's BTLE_Transfer sample app available on their developer portal.

Comment: If I am using hardware to communicate with iphone then in hardware also I need to run software with whose help i can connect both device with bluetooth?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question entirely. My limited understanding of the android Bluetooth 4.0 protocol stack is that they do not support the required protocol bits to make the phone into a peripheral, as "peripheral" is defined in the iOS CoreBluetooth context. Are there workarounds for this? I do not know. I suppose it is possible to use an alternate protocol stack, but what that means in a practical sense, I don't know. My Android knowledge is limited.